# how to wait for trigger taking action in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dispatcher

I have a program, where there is a loading image, when a long lasting action taking place. I want to use a `ContentControl`, which holds a `Button` for the action, or show a loading `Image`. I have set a `Trigger` to `IsLoading` property, so it can swap the `Content`.

View:

```
<Window x:Class="UIHangsTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UIHangsTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl" >
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Button Content="shiny disappearing button" Command="{Binding DoCommand}" IsDefault="True" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Image />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Use this, if You need to run the long running task on the UI (dispatcher) thread.
ViewModel:

```
namespace UIHangsTest
{
    using System;
    using DevExpress.Mvvm;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    public class VM: ViewModelBase
    {
        public VM()
        {
            DoCommand = new DelegateCommand(Do, () => true);
            IsLoading = false;
        }

        private void Do()
        {
            // I have set some content control's trigger to show a waiting symbol if IsLoading is true.
            IsLoading = true;
            var handle = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            // shows 1.                
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            // I'd like to wait for the UI to complete the swapping of ContentControl's Content
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                handle.Set();
                // shows 1
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }), DispatcherPriority.Background);

            handle.Wait();
            // for 1 second, the empty image should be visible, but it's the half clicked Button.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IsLoading = false;
        }

        public DelegateCommand DoCommand { get; private set; }

        // not working:
        // public bool IsLoading { get; set; }

        // working:
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLoading;
            }
            set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not know, that the Do command will be run on the UI thread. But also, if I change the code, so the long lasting action runs on the background thread, it still not changes the `Content` to the empty `Image`, if You not raising property changed (ˇ_ˇ’!l).

Use this, if You can run the long running task on some background thread:

```
private void Do()
{
    IsLoading = true;
    // shows 1
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // shows 5
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        //this operation is performed on a background thread...
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        IsLoading = false;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

edit:

The first approach works. So if You change only the `IsLoading` setter to have `RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading")`, than it will properly work. No need to put the long running task in the background thread (which I wanted to avoid in the first place). In my specific case the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` was a long running process, which also needed to run on the UI (dispatcher) thread, because of possible Dialog window creation to inform users about exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform the long-running operation, i.e. `Thread.Sleep` in this case, on a background thread:

```
private void Do()
{
    IsLoading = true;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //this operation is performed on a background thread...
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        IsLoading = false;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

The UI thread cannot both sleep and update your view at the same time.

You also need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `IsLoading` property:

```
private bool _isLoading;
public bool IsLoading
{
    get { return _isLoading; }
    set { _isLoading = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer @mm8, but the `Image` is not showing. I'm a bit closer to the solution tho. Please check the updated question

Comment: You also need to raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the IsLoading property. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ohh. I'm stupid. Thanks. I skipped some trivial code from the minimal example